# MySql Join two table with column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables in my MySQL database:

Cars table:

```
+----Cars   Table-----+
+---------------------+
| id | BMW   | KIA    |-and another cars
+----+----------+-----+
| 1  | M5    | Rio    |
| 2  | Z1    | Serato |
| 3  | X5    | Sorento|
```

Like table:

```
+----------------------+-----+
| id | Cars_id| Cars   |ip   |
+----+----------+------+-----+
| 1  |   1    | KIA    |1.0.1|
| 2  |   1    | BMW    |1.0.1|
```

Basically, the Cars table have more cars Mark and their models.

**My question is, how Join this tables - Like.Cars_id=Cars.id and Like.Cars=Cars.Column names?.**

So, I would like a query like this:

```
SELECT Cars.BMW, Cars.KIA,  COUNT(Like.ip) AS likes
FROM CARS_Table
    LEFT JOIN Like_table
        ON Cars.id = Like.Cars_id AND what?
```

Comment: you should normalize your cars table  ..

Comment: i want i can count each cars models ip

Comment: how i can normalize cars table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should normalize the table  this way

```
Brand 
id, name  
1, BMW 
2, KIA 
3, ...

cars 
id, id_brand, car_name 
1, 1, M5 
2, 1, Z1 
3, 1, X5 
4, 2, Rio 
5, 2, Serato 
6, 2, Sorento 

like_table  

id, cars_id, ip 
1, 1, 1.0.1 
2, 1, 1.0.1 


select b.name, c.name, count(ip)
from  like_table l 
inner join  cars c on l.cars_id = c.id 
inner join  Brand b on b.id = c.id_brand
group by b.name, c.name
```

in this way is easy get the like for car but also like for brand and others

```
select b.name count(ip)
from  like_table l 
inner join  cars c on l.cars_id = c.id 
inner join  Brand b on b.id = c.id_brand
group by b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to count cars model ip

then no need join between two tables,below query will count model ip

```
select Cars,  count(ip) from Like_table    
group by Cars
```